# Apache redirect not working quite right

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am setting up a redirect for my wedding website so that `http://www.mydomain.com/rsvp.php/q/something` redirects to `http://www.mydomain.com/rsvp.php?q=something`, but only on the server-side (that is, the client still sees `rsvp.php/q/something` in their address bar).

Now, I have the following in my apache config for this site:

```
<VirtualHost *>
        ServerAdmin my@email.com
        ServerName www.mydomain.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/www.mydomain.com
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteRule ^/rsvp.php/q/(.*) /rsvp.php?q=$1
</VirtualHost>
```

Now, I also have a meta-redirect at the top of the PHP file (in the event that the user doesn't have anything in the q query variable) that redirects to index.html:

```
<?php
  $userHash = $_GET['q'];
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
        <head>
                <title>Wedding - RSVP Page</title>
<?php

        // If we don't have a user hash, then let's redirect to the main
        // page.
        if (!$userHash) {
          echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://www.mydomain.com/">';
        }
?>
```

Again, this seems to work ok, with one exception. I'm using a form for the user to input their RSVP data. On submit, it calls a script, `submit-form.php`. When the address http://www.mydomain.com/getID.php is accessed, it redirects to index.html, which is not what I want.

If I remove the `RewriteRule`, it works as expected, with the exception that I don't get a nice url (I have to use `q=something` instead of `q/something`). I'm not very good at mod_rewrite, so I'm wondering if someone could give me some assistance to let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to tell apache not to rewrite existing files, using `RewriteCond`.

in your .htaccess add the following code:

```
rewriteengine on
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  #not a directory
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  #not a file
RewriteRule ^rvsp/([^/\.]+)?$  rvsp.php?q=$1
```

than, in your rvsp.php file, add this code:

```
<?php
$q = $_GET['q'];
?>
```

the action in the form `getID.php` should look like this:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/rvsp/query
```

where `query` is the user input

Comment: Sorry... I didn't read the post correctly enough. This works well, thank you.